# PHPWord fixed cell width

Tags: php, phpword, fixed-width

I am trying to create a table with cells width a fixed width.
Let's say I have this code:

```
$table->addCell(300)->addText('first');
$table->addCell(300)->addText('text that is very looooooooong');
```

The first cell's 300 width is ignored and is crushed against the left side of the page like this:

> f
> i
> r
> s
> t

My second cell is going to contain large texts, but I want that cell to maintain it's width.
I couldn't find it anywhere on the web so I am asking if somebody knows what I will have to do here.

Comment: Value `300` is in twips by default, where `1440 twips = 1 inch = 2.54 cm`. You need to either calculate absolute column width against absolute inner page width or set the table to use `percent` units and then use also percent width for columns. See https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/develop/styles.html#table

Answer (score 4):

Remeber that these values are TWIPS and 300 Twips are mere 5mm.
Not enough room to hold more than 1 character.

Here is a calculator that helps you to convert values:

[Topgrapy Calculator](http://endmemo.com/convert/topography.php)

Also you might use the built in conversion functions in Shared\Font.php like this:

```
$helper= new PHPWord_Shared_Font();
//convert 5cm to Twips
$inTwips=$helper->centimeterSizeToTwips(5);
```

I have not tried this so far.

Comment: What about fixed cell width? I guess the answer is incomplete, can you help us?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that you have to set style "layout" fixed on your table like below

```
$fancyTableStyle = [
    'borderSize'  => 6,
    'borderColor' => '000000',
    'cellMargin'  => 80,
    'alignment'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER,
    'layout'      => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::LAYOUT_FIXED,
];
$table = $section->addTable($fancyTableStyle);
```

and then the long word will wrap itself inside the cell.

If you preset a table style on your phpword object, the layout style won't work.

```
$fancyTableStyleName = 'Fancy Table';
$fancyTableStyle = [
    'borderSize'  => 6,
    'borderColor' => '000000',
    'cellMargin'  => 80,
    'alignment'   => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER,
    'layout'      => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::LAYOUT_FIXED,
];
//table will not be fixed
$table = $section->addTable($fancyTableStyleName);
```

In ms word you also need to set the autofit option directly on each table, maybe that's why.